# Почему не загружается содержимое Iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, fancybox

до полной загрузки сайта фрейм загружается полностью,
а после полной загрузки сайта содержимое фрейма не подгружается

плагин fancybox

[image: после]

[image: до]

Comment: посмотреть бы на сам сайт, может ссылку приложите.
Ну а вообще это может быть связано с какими ни будь стилями на сайте или js событиями типа после загрузки страницы мы прячем содержимое  попапа. Так же возможно что на сайте стоит защита от фрейма и браузер чекает это и запрещает использовать iframe. Так же посмотрел бы в сторону расширений браузера они часто ломают верстку.

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий https://clck.ru/EQbTx - тестовый домен. самое странное что на тестовом работает все нормально а но проде нет... что за бред ума не приложу...

Comment: я смотрю у вас сайт на 1C-Bitrix а значит там есть защита от фрейма, выключите ее и попробуйте снова должно заработать. Про это можно почитать можно тут https://klondike-studio.ru/blog/vebvizor-on-bitriks